# Insert a formatted textbox in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint, shapes, formatted

I want to **write VBA code for PowerPoint that inserts a preformatted textbox**, specifically wrt to bullet formatting on multiple levels (i.e. first level no bullet, second level round bullet, third indented level a dash bullet, fourth intended level a square bullet). See screenshot for example of formatting

[image]

**What I have tried**

- I have a TextPlaceholder (so called in Selection Pane) in Slide Master that is formatted like I want and I hope I can insert that using VBA, but that does not seem to work.
- Changing default text box in PPT and then using VBA to simple insert textbox VBA gets me halfway there, because it only allows me to define the first bullet level.

**My question is**

1. Is it possible to use VBA to insert a formatted a shape / textbox that adheres to format in the Slide Master (e.g.  'TextPlaceholder' in Selection Pane)?
2. If not, is there a different solution to insert a formatted textbox that adheres to my desired bullet levels?

Thank you
Mike

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create textboxes with up to 9 levels of formatting by editing the OOXML of the file. Here are my how-to articles: [OOXML Hacking: Text Box Styles](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/12/xml-hacking-text-box-styles/) [OOXML Hacking: Styled Text Boxes Complete](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/12/xml-hacking-styled-text-boxes-complete/). Those articles cover manual editing of the OOXML.

You can programmatically manipulate OOXML with VBA code using the downloads mentioned in this article: [Edit OOXML with VBA - Cool Code](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2021/03/edit-ooxml-with-vba-cool-code/). Using this code, find the **bodyStyle** section in *slideMaster1.xml*, copy the section and paste it into the **defaultTextStyle** section of *presentation.xml*.

Comment: Yes, there's a learning curve, but in actual operation it's just a single VBA copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you John! I dove into this and just like you said - bit of a learning curve but the options it opens is fantastic! Exactly what i was looking for

Comment: If you found it useful, please give my answer an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: I dont seem (yet) able to, I have tried